# Hibernate annotations double[]

Tags: hibernate

What is the correct annotation to persist a double[] in hibernate?

e.g.

private double[] myData;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` is used to persist collections of primitive data.

Comment: Do you have an example (complains I need an @OrderColumn)? Will this persist to a separate table?

Comment: yes, it will be persisted to a separate table. I'd suggest to use a `List<Double>` instead of an array though

Comment: @DD. as always, all the examples can be found in the Hibernate reference documentation. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/